# How does NHibernate know which table to save to?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I did some research since I never used nhibernate before and I found that to save an entity to the database, I should use `"SaveOrUpdate()"` so I have the following:

```
Object myObject = new Object { someProperty="something" };
using (ISession session = NHibernateSessionFactoryManager.Factory.OpenSession())
{
    session.SaveOrUpdate(myObject);
}
```

do I have to specify somewhere which table I'm saving to, or does NHibernate figure that out from the object type?

Comment: The right one is the second one: `NHibernate figure that out from the object type`. But you'll need a mapping! :-) And I do hope the first line is: `MyMappedObject myObject = new MyMappedObject { someProperty="something" };`

Comment: ah ok, a mapping huh. I think someone else wrote one somewhere in the application... Yea I think it is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the `ISession` interface, you'll see that there are only two `SaveOrUpdate` methods:

```
void SaveOrUpdate(object obj);

void SaveOrUpdate(string entityName, object obj);
```

You are using the first one, that uses the mapping that you defined to map the `obj.GetType()` to a table.

There is another overload that uses `entityName` that should be used if you use the

> Persistent entities don't necessarily have to be represented as POCO classes at runtime. NHibernate also supports dynamic models (using Dictionaries of Dictionarys at runtime) . With this approach, you don't write persistent classes, only mapping files.

In these mapping files you have to define an entity-name.